# Encode nested structs using web3

Tags: web3js, struct, encoding, abiencoderv2

I'm using Solidity 0.8.0 (so I'm using `ABIEncoderV2`) and web3.js 1.3.4 and I'm trying to call a contract's method passing a nested struct.

```
erc1155.methods.safeBatchTransferFrom(
            owner,
            orchestratorAddress,
            [tokenAId, tokenBId],
            [tokenAAmount, tokenBAmount],
            payload
        ).send({ from: owner });
```

where my `payload` is

```
let payload = [
            operationId,
            [
                [
                    ['0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000', '42', '43', true]
                ],
                receiver
            ]
        ];
```

Since I take advantage of the ERC1155 callback `onERC1155BatchReceived()` in my orchestrator contract, currently I don't even load it in the front-end. I know that latest Solidity versions exposes struct informations in the ABIs, so maybe this could be part of the problem.

However, `operationId` is an `uint256` and `receiver` is an address, in my contract I use two consecutive `abi.decode()`. `[['0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000', '42', '43', true]` is a vector of struct such this:

```
struct MyStruct {
        address fieldA;
        uint256 fieldB;
        uint256 fieldC;
        bool fieldD;
    }
```

Indeed one of these fields should be a struct itself, but even with the simplification I used here I get the same error when I try to send the transaction:

```
Error: invalid arrayify value (argument="value", value=["6",[[["0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000","42","43",true]],"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"]], code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=bytes/5.0.9)
    at t.value (index.ts:205)
    at t.value (index.ts:217)
    at t.value (index.ts:221)
    at c (index.ts:136)
    at r.value (bytes.ts:13)
    at array.ts:62
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at m (array.ts:54)
    at r.value (tuple.ts:23)
    at t.value (abi-coder.ts:106)
```

Comment: The last parameter `payload` from `safeTransferFrom` is `bytes`, so you need to encode it as bytes. Since the correct encoding depends on the usage how is it decoded?